# Commensurability and normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Two groups $G_1,G_2$ are *(abstractly) commensurable* if there exist isomorphic finite-index subgroups $H_1 \leq G_1$, $H_2 \leq G_2$.

> **Question:** If $G_1,G_2$ are commensurable, do there exist two isomorphic **normal** finite-index subgroups $H_1 \lhd G_1$, $H_2 \lhd G_2$?

Here, I am assuming that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are finitely generated. As a consequence, one of the two subgroups can be chosen normal, but can they be chosen normal simultaneously? If the answer is negative in full generality, I am also interested in partial positive answer. For instance, we may assume that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are residually finite.

Comment: Do you mean "commesurable"?

Comment: @Shaun. It's definitely spelt with the "n" (I even checked [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensurability_(group_theory)) :-) )

Comment: I guess there are counterexamples, even among f.g. residually finite groups. I don't even know the answer for f.g. nilpotent groups (it's positive for the easiest ones, but this is not representative).